# Does compressing a PNG file affect idat header only?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, compression, png

I want to parse PNG file into chunks.

I know that if the file compressed the IDAT chunk will be affected, will it affect other chunks (Ancillary Chunks) ?

Read about the compression [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression) and seems that other chunks will not be affected.

Comment: What do you mean by *"affected"* please? The `zTXt` chunk is compressed too - if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes that's what I mean, affected means that the chunks will be different between compressed and uncompressed file

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you have a PNG file and you are trying to compress it with `gzip` or something? PNGs are pretty much always compressed already when created. The IDAT and zTxt chunks are compressed already. You can still parse/extract the chunks in a PNG without decompressing the IDAT and zTxt.

Comment: I want to get all of the chunks of the PNG file (using my code) except the IDAT for analysis and comparison. So I wanted to know if I can ignore the compression factor (because it doesn't affect my chunks) or no, if zTxt is compressed so I can't ignore and need to decompress before running the comparison. Hope it's more clear now and thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see why the compression makes any difference. You can still seek to the next chunk and grab it whether the data are compressed or not - the chunk headers (which contain the chunk sizes and allow you to skip to the next chunk) themselves are never compressed.